How to disable NFC NDEF tag on iOS when my app is open?
I am working on an open-source iOS application that works with a companion NFC card to store passwords, a bit like a physical password manager. On the smartcard, there is an applet that manages the passwords, and an NDEF applet that allows to store a short programmable NDEF message (The NDEF protocols is a standard that allows to tap a card on the phone to automatically exchange data or trigger some action).
My goal is to use the NDEF tag to automatically open the iOS application when the user taps the card. I have implemented the NDEF support in the application using universal link as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading.

When the iOS application is NOT open, and the user taps his card on the iPhone, a pop up appears to propose to open the application for the user. If the user taps the popup, the application opens as expected.

However, once the application is open, when the user scan the card (i.e. to use password manager applet to get a password through NFC, so not with the NDEF applet), the same NDEF pop up appears regularly to propose to open the application (which is already running!). This is very inconvenient and basically makes the app unusable.


Is there any way to deactivate the NDEF background scan, or configure the application to intercept NDEF tags when the application is already open, so that the NDEF popup does not appear when the application is already running?
Note that on android, the process works as expected: if the application is not open, the application opens automatically when user taps the card (no pop up displayed). If the app is already open, nothing happens when the NDEF tag is detected (using same NDEF tag with universal link).
